# Save value of query

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i save a value from a query in `NSMutableArray`.

```
tempQuery=[@"select * from iapp_tbl_questions where id= " stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowid1]];


const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
     NSLog(@"vt", vt);
    vt=[[[Question1 alloc]init]autorelease];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {

        vt.question=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement1,3)];

    }
}
return vt;
```

Thanks...

Comment: what error you get when you trying this?

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];
 NSMutableArray *results = nil;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement1,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
     NSLog(@"vt", vt);
    results= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement1)==SQLITE_ROW) {
vt=[[[Question1 alloc]init]autorelease];
        vt.question=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement1,3)];
[results addObject:vt];

    }
}
return results;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i have added the above code in my application. But it gives me a crash if i returning results.

Comment: have u changed ur return type? can u post what is displayed on the console?