# How to save table column sqlite3 values in an array

Tags: iphone

How to save a table column sqlite3 values in an array.

```
tempQuery=[@"select * from iapp_tbl_cases where casenum=" 
             stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowid]];

const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

    qt=[[[Question alloc]init]autorelease];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        qt.cases=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)];
        return qt;
    }
```

Comment: are you getting value in qt.cases from database?and want that value to be stored in array?

Comment: Yes i am getting qt.cases values from database and i want that value to store in an array

Comment: why did you add question again? it is posted already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820119/save-value-of-query

Answer (score 0):

```
Create one array and store the value as below:
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
tempQuery=[@"select * from iapp_tbl_cases where casenum=" 
             stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowid]];

const char *query2=[tempQuery UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query2,-1,&statement,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {

    qt=[[[Question alloc]init]autorelease];
    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        qt.cases=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)];
[arr addObject:qt.cases];
 NSLog(@"arr is %@",[arr description]);
        
    }
```